# Entity relation with itself

Tags: erd, database-diagrams, dbms

I want to make an ER diagram for scientific research papers, one of the constraints is that a paper shouldn't cite itself.
I'm not very sure how to achieve this, as [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162539/entity-set-that-has-a-relationship-with-itself) question points out, the ER diagram doesn't convey whether a paper can cite itself or not. Is there a way to achieve this in ER diagrams?

Comment: I'm not sure how I see the example you linked relates to your scenario. But if you provided your ER diagram so far, it might help. In an ER diagram, foreign key relationships represent the ability to relate an entity to another entity (which could be itself). Lacking a foreign key relationship should **implicitly** indicate an entity is not related to another entity. That's the extent of ER diagrams regarding referential integrity. So I'm not sure if you have any issue to solve at all, but seeing your ER diagram would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.